# Инициализация нескольких объектов одновременно

Tags: jquery, javascript

Есть 6 (могут быть и больше) полей (div) на странице, каждое поле я рассматриваю как объект.

```
function Field(obj, params){
    ....
    self init=function(){
       Инициализирует поле: обновление в нужный момент; присвоение полю элементов итд
    }
    self edit = function(){
       Открывает модал данному полю для редактирования настроек итд.
    }
    ....
    self.init();
}
```

Подскажите, как при загрузке страницы инициализировать все поля?

```
  field_1=new Field("id поля");
```

Как найти все поля и проинициализировать, если каждое поле имеет id? Как быть если поля классифицированы?

Пиши в коммент, если что не понятно, не знаю как иначе сформулировать вопрос.

Comment: почитай про то как делать плагины. думаю поможет.

Comment: Что за конструкция self init?Может var self=this.  self.init=

Comment: @kaza4ok так оно и есть, я же всю конструкцию не привел.

Answer (score 1):

Я не знаю, что вы имели в виду, но надеюсь, что данный код поможет вам разобраться

```
// создадим переменную-функцию
var Field = function (obj, params) {
  var init = function(){
    if (obj.className.search('field-active')===-1) { // если объект не "инициализирован"
        console.log(obj.id); // выведем в консоль его id
        obj.className = obj.className + ' field-active'; // "инициализируем" объект
    }
  }
  init(); 
}

divs = document.getElementsByTagName('div') // найдем все div

for (i in divs) {
   var node = divs[i];
   if (node.id) Field (node); // инициализируем, если есть id
}
```

Попробуйте запустить его на этой странице. Первый раз он выведет все `id` (среди найденных `div`), во второй раз он не выведет ничего, т.к. все объекты будут "инициализированы".

P.S. А что вы понимаете под инициализацией?

Comment: инициализаwbя в моем случае - это вызов метода init. Что-то в этом роде я и хотел. Даже так и подумывал, но хотел более красивое решение.